# Software Quality - checkbox and radio

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am trying to select a field (checkbox), however I am not able to, using code below:

```
WebElement comboboxElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"chkRANGE_0_2K\"]"));
        comboboxElement.click();
```

I've also tried this:

```
WebElement comboboxElement = driver.findElement(By.id("chkRANGE_2K_5K"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"chkRANGE_2K_5K\"]")).click();

Select combobox = new Select(comboboxElement);    
dropdown.selectByValue("RANGE_0_2K");
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="RANGE_0_2K" id="chkRANGE_0_2K" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid xh-highlight">
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

From the above html provided, It is clear that the `input` tag is of `type='checkbox'`.

And you are trying to perform actions related to a `select` tag (like `selectByValue`) on an `input` tag of `type checkbox`.

Actions that can be performed on an checkbox are `click()` etc..

Answer (score 0):

It is a checkbox how you are able to select it, Select class is used to select value from drop down

Use this code to click on checkbox

```
WebElement ele= driver.findElement(By.id("chkRANGE_0_2K"));
ele.click();
```